# How to drop rows with a column value that takes less than x percent of the total csv dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For example i have this table

| name | hobby |
| --- | --- |
| jake | drawing |
| sofia | coding |
| john | drawing |
| henry | coding |
| susan | dancing |
| tony | coding |
| harry | drawing |
| peter | coding |
| annie | coding |
| danny | badminton |

From the table above, drawing takes 30% and coding each takes 50% of the dataset while dancing and badminton takes only 10%
How can I eliminate rows that has less than x% of the dataset like the dancing and badminton row?
Since I want to visualize it using pyplot to visualize a large dataset but the x values keep overlapping so I want to remove unimportant data

Comment: `df["hobby"].value_counts(normalize=True)*100` would give you the percentage of each hobby.

Comment: So that works but how to remove them from the old dataset and make a new dataset from it? Im quite new to pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd

name = ['jake', 'sofia', 'john', 'henry', 'susan', 'tony', 'harry', 'peter', 'annie', 'danny']
hobby = ['drawing', 'coding', 'drawing', 'coding', 'dancing', 'coding', 'drawing', 'coding', 'coding', 'badminton']

df = pd.DataFrame(name, columns={'Name'})
df['Hobby'] = hobby

# add percentage values in the df

percentage = (df['Hobby'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).to_dict()
list_per = [percentage[hobby] for hobby in list(df['Hobby'])]
df['Percentage'] = list_per

# remove rows


def remove_rows(threshold, df):
    result = df.drop(df[df.Percentage <= threshold].index)
    result = result[["Name", "Hobby"]]
    return result

new_df = remove_rows(30, df)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Can you explain the `list_per = [percentage[hobby] for hobby in list(df['Hobby'])]` part? Does "hobby" depends on the hobby list above or it depends on the for loop

Comment: create a new column in the dataframe, that contains the percentage of the hobby in the entire set. it depends on the internal loop, read about comprehensive loop.

Comment: hmm im getting keyerror nan in the list_per line. it might have something to do with the hobby list since im working with a quite large dataset so i cant make a list manually. ill try to make it work

Comment: once you read your csv, check how your hobby column is called. and change it from df['Hobby'] to the name you need. maybe you need to change it from Hobby to hobby

Comment: Nevermind I got it working. I forgot to remove nan/null rows

Comment: The `columns=['Name']` while creating the df.